# Error Sending multiple json messages

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I have an issue with json, 
I have a function that send a json array

```
public function repondMessage($etat=true,$message)
{
    $msg =  array($etat,$message);
    return '{"msg":'.json_encode($msg).'}';
}
```

and I get the Json array correctly when just one error sent

like this one:

```
if(a=1)
{
echo respondeMessage(false,'Error');
}
```

and jQuery:

```
    console.log(data);
    var resp = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
    console.log(resp);
```

I Get the result which is fine for me:

```
{"msg":[false,"Error"]}
```

but when I get two messages at the same time , when I make a test like that

```
if(a=1)
{
echo respondeMessage(false,'Error');
}

if(b=1)
{
echo respondeMessage(false,'Error2');
}
```

this what happen : (I don't how to separete the two Json)

```
{"msg":[false,"Error"]}{"msg":[false,"Error2"]}

    Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
```

Comment: You cannot send multiple responses like that, instead add the responces to and array and send them all at once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my comment, you cannot send multiple responses, instead add the responses to and array and send them all at once

```
public function respondMessage($message)
{
    $msg =  array('msg'=>$message);
    //Always send the correct header
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($msg);
    //and stop execution after sending the response - any further output is invalid
    die();
}
$errors=[];
if($a=1)
{
    $errors[]=[false=>'Error'];
}

if($b=1)
{
    $errors[]=[false=>'Error2'];
}

if(!empty($errors){
    respondMessage($errors);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By invoking your respond function you are responding multiple times.  From your code, I believe the intent is to respond as follows:

```
{"msg":[false, "Error", "Error2"]}
```

If that is the case, my recommendation would be the following structure in your invoking context to provide those results:

```
$errors = [];
if($a=1){
    $errors[] = 'Error';
}

if($b=1){
    $errors[] = 'Error2';
}
if( count( $errors ) ){
    respondMessage( true, $errors );
}
```